# GLES Shader issue on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, glsl, shader

I have some issue with a fragment shader using Android. The shader is displaying well on the emulator

[image: http://easy-pics.net/images/scr2.png]

But on any phone / tablet I have

[image]

Also if I lock/unlock the phone/tablet or tilt it (anything that refresh the display), it makes the ambient light appear (but doesnt fix the whole pb) (cant post picture because of limitation of the site).

Looks to me like an issue of int / float things, but I really cant figure it out, does something here have an idea ?

Here is the shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 lightVec[2];
varying vec3 eyeVec;
varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D textureUnit0;
uniform sampler2D textureUnit1;

uniform vec3 diffuseColors[8];
uniform vec3 specularColors[8];

uniform vec4 ambientColor;

uniform float invRadius; 
uniform float heightScale;

void main ()
{
    vec4 vAmbient = ambientColor;
    vec3 vVec = normalize(eyeVec);

    float height = texture2D(textureUnit1, texCoord).a;
    vec2 offset = vVec.xy * (height * 2.0 - 1.0) *heightScale;
    vec2 newTexCoord = texCoord + offset;

    vec4 base = texture2D(textureUnit0, newTexCoord);
    vec3 bump = normalize(texture2D(textureUnit1, newTexCoord).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);

    // First light source

    float distSqr = dot(lightVec[0], lightVec[0]);
    float att = clamp(1.0 - invRadius * sqrt(distSqr), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 lVec = lightVec[0] * inversesqrt(distSqr);

    float diffuse = max(dot(lVec, bump), 0.0);
    vec4 vDiffuse = vec4(diffuseColors[0],0.0) * diffuse;   

    float specular = pow(clamp(dot(reflect(-lVec, bump), vVec), 0.0, 1.0), 0.85);
    vec4 vSpecular = vec4(specularColors[0],0.0) * specular;    

    gl_FragColor = (vAmbient*base + vDiffuse*base + vSpecular) * att*2.0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the precision to `highp`? This looks like some kind of precision/overflow issue. Not sure where in the shader it would be happening, though. I guess if `lightVec[0]` is very long. I thought it might be an invalid (negative) argument to `sqrt()` or `pow()`, but those look fine. I have seen very similar effects before, and it was either overflow, or a division by 0.

Comment: Hello, yes it is definitly this kind of issue, but highp doesnt solve it
I temporally replaced float distSqr = dot(lightVec[0], lightVec[0]); by 50000, no glitch anymore (but i cut the feature down)
thanks